# How to make ActiveX textbox readonly but scrollable in Excel 2013?

Tags: excel, textbox

I want to make a multiline ActiveX textbox readonly in Excel 2013 but still allow the user to scroll the text. I have multiline set to true and i have a vertical scrollbar visible. However I cannot find a way to prevent the user from changing the textbox contents but still be able to use the textbox scrollbars. I dont want the user to be able to edit the textbox contents.
I have to use ActiveX. A label wont work because it cant have scrollbars. Disabling the textbox also disables the scrollbars. The Locked property, as so many people point to as the solution, is completely useless in Excel 2013 and does nothing--it has absolutely no effect on anything regardless if it's set to true or false.  I also looked into trying to use the OnChange and other events for the textbox but they dont seem be useful...you just know that something has happened but you cant prevent anything. I would prefer not to use the hackish strategy of constantly storing the text in a variable and the resetting the Text property whenever you get an OnChange.
Please refrain from providing other solutions such as message boxes, using a large textbox or cell to avoid the need for scrolling, etc. I want to use a textbox control. This is for showing lengthy status messages to the user.  I also want to avoid having to protect the sheet or entire workbook, although my testing with linked cells and protection has made no difference.
I dont understand why the simplest concept is so incredibly difficult to make happen. I understand that Microsoft is useless but that's beside the point. Most of the time you have to work around their bugs (they often call them features) but this is ridiculous. 
Someone must have a solution to this problem that doesnt require 3rd party controls.